# I have a lot of 404 error when I try to do `do-release-upgrade`

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my version of ubuntu. I have Ubuntu 13.04 and when I do `sudo do-release-upgrade` I have this trace :

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
Recherche d'une nouvelle version d'Ubuntu
Votre version d'Ubuntu n'est plus prise en charge.
Pour plus d'informations sur la mise à jour, veuillez visiter :
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Prendre :1 Signature de l'outil de mise à niveau [198 B]
Prendre :2 Outil de mise à niveau [1 134 kB]
1 134 k o téléchargés en 0s (0  o/s)
authentification de 'saucy.tar.gz' avec 'saucy.tar.gz.gpg'
extraction de 'saucy.tar.gz'

Lecture du cache

Vérification du gestionnaire de paquets
Lecture des listes de paquets… Terminé
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état… Terminé
Construction des structures de données… Terminé
Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg
Att http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg
Att http://archive.canonical.com saucy Release.gpg
Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release.gpg
Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release
Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release
Att http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release
Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates Release.gpg
Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages
Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main amd64 Packages
Att http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources
Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy-backports Release.gpg
Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe amd64 Packages
Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Att http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages
Att http://archive.canonical.com saucy Release.gpg
Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted amd64 Packages
Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe amd64 Packages
Att http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages
Att http://archive.canonical.com saucy Release
Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse amd64 Packages
Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates Release
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr_CA

Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages
Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy-backports Release
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr

Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe i386 Packages
Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted i386 Packages
Att http://archive.canonical.com saucy Release
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en

Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted i386 Packages
Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe i386 Packages
Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/main Sources

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US

Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse i386 Packages
Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/restricted Sources

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr_CA

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr_CA

Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-fr_CA

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr

Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/universe Sources

Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr
Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en

Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/multiverse Sources

Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-fr

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US

Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en
Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-fr_CA

Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en_US

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr_CA

Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages

Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-fr
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-fr_CA

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr

Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/universe amd64 Packages

Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-fr

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en

Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-en_US

Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en
Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/main i386 Packages

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-fr_CA

Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en_US

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr_CA

Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/restricted i386 Packages

Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-fr
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-fr_CA

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr

Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/universe i386 Packages

Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-en_US

Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-fr

Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-fr_CA

Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en
Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/main Translation-fr_CA

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US

Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-fr
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr_CA
Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/main Translation-fr

Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en_US

Att http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-fr_CA

Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/main Translation-en

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-en_US

Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-fr

Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en
Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/main Translation-en_US

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-fr_CA

Att http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-fr_CA

Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US

Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-fr

Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en_US
```

I have a ton of error messages and some 404 errors.

This is my /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _saucy Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ saucy main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ saucy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ saucy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ saucy partner
# deb http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot all main # désactivé pour la mise à niveau vers saucy
# deb-src http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot all main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main universe restricted multiverse
```

What can I do to correct my pathes?

Comment: Why don't you use update manager?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/455741/upgrade-from-13-04-to-14-04 (Kubuntu) Read my answer there.

Comment: @Pandya, add an anwser and I will accept it.

Comment: @arsaKasra, the update manager does not works for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Release Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseTeam#Releases.End_of_life), Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) life ended on January 27,2014. Hence you may not getting security update.

[image]

For more info visit : [Ubuntu-announce](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2014-January/000178.html).

So, Recommanded to install fresh Ubuntu 14.04 **which will support until April-2019** (can be downloaded from http://www.ubuntu.com/download)