# Upgrade from 13.04 to 14.04

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, kubuntu, 14.04, software-sources

I have Kubuntu 13.04 (unsupported release), and want to upgrade it to 14.04.
When I'm trying to run `do-release-upgrade` I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 123, in 
>       "%(url)s\n") % { 'url' : url }) ValueError: unsupported format character '?' (0xa) at index 55

I know that I should upgrade to 13.10 first. I read the documentation, but when I tried to add `old-releases` repository to my sources list, something like `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse` I get 404 error while updating my sources.

Is this documentation too old to help me? Where can I find newer docs? Or can you show me other way to upgrade my OS?

Answer (score 3):

Edit /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade and comment out lines 123 - 127

```
# make sure to inform the user if his distro is no longer supported
# this will make it appear in motd (that calls do-release-upgrade in
#  check-new-release mode)
#  if m.no_longer_supported is not None:
#    url = "http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife"
#    print(_("Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore."))
#    print(_("For upgrade information, please visit:\n"
#            "%(url)s\n") % { 'url' : url })
```

Make sure to remove comments after upgrade!

Comment: Thank you! Allowed me to get from 13.04 to 13.10 (the old-releases trick) and now to 14.04 :)

Answer (score 1):

Not an official tutorial, but worked successfully for me with lubuntu.


1. Change /etc/apt/sources.list to a 13.10 repository

   (use the list generator from http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)


2. apt-get update  && apt-get upgrade && reboot &&  apt-get dist-upgrade

   (will upgrade to 13.10. Don't panik if your desktop is lost. Solve this by clearing desktop configs in your /home/userxxx and re-login)


3. reboot (just in case)


4. start the software updater and run the 14.04 LTS upgrade 


5. Your're done. 

   May take quite a bit of time (2 dist upgrades) and is not guaranteed to 

   work in every situation, but if not, re-installing is still an option.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a new/clean install of **14.04 LTS**.

---

You might be able to upgrade to **13.10** by having that on other media (eg. USB stick).

*But there is no support (past Jan-2014) for **13.04**, for any issue that might occur.*